# best way to format spacing for input form html

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have the following code that basically is a input form as I have it now the spacing between the title of each field and the field are all lined up properly when executed on my browser but when I try it on another browser some of the spacing is off, what is the best way to align the input so that it will render the same on all browsers?

```
<div style="z-index:12; position:absolute">
<font style="color:#FF6600; font-family:pirulen">
*Name: <input type="text" name="name" style=" margin-left:70px" size="30px" /><br/>
*Email: <input type="email" name="email"  style="margin-left:70px; margin-top:5px; " size="30px"  /><br/>
Company: <input type="text" name="company"  style="margin-left:28px; margin-top:5px"  size="30px" /><br/>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"  style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:5px"  size="30px" /><br/>
Address 2: <input type="text" name="address2"  style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px"  size="30px" /><br/>
City: <input type="text" name="city"  style="margin-left:92px; margin-top:5px"  size="30px" /><br/>
State: <input type="text" name="state"  style="margin-left:65px; margin-top:5px"  size="30px" /><br/>
Zip: <input type="text" name="zip"  style="margin-left:106px; margin-top:5px"  size="30px" /><br/>
*Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"  style="margin-left:58px; margin-top:5px"  size="30px" /><br/>
*Comments:<textarea style=" margin-left:12px; margin-top:5px; vertical-align:top; resize:none"   name="comments" cols="30" rows="10" draggable="false"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left:150px" />
```

Thanks

Comment: First, I would recommend not using inline styles. It's a maintenance nightmare (if you want to change things, you have to go hunt it in your markup each time - stylesheets were made to help you separate concerns, in this case markup vs. style. Second, and more important to your question, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish - I suggest creating a jsfiddle to demonstrate what you've got then tell us how you want it relative to that. It's very difficult to translate what you have here into anything visual.

Comment: Basically i just want a form that has for example name: and then input field and the same idea for email, company,address etc.  My concern is the spacing between the name and the input field, if I leave it alone all the input fields will be right beside their respective title for example name will be beside name input,  what I want to do is be able to align all inputs, in my code i do that using margins but it is different on different values/computers.

Comment: If you want everything aligned like I believe you're looking for, I recommend something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LpArB/

Comment: Alternatively, you can align just the input fields: http://jsfiddle.net/LpArB/1/ - just remove the text-align rule on the labels to accomplish this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a table, with labels (titles) in one column, fields in another. Having done that, you can then easily test different stylistic settings. The default rendering (fields aligned to the left) is not too bad, but consider right-aligning the labels; you may find this even better. You won’t need any pixel widths, since browsers automatically make each column as wide as needed for its widest cell contents. No other approach does this, except the use of CSS to simulate an HTML table (a clumsier way, which does not work on many versions of IE still in use).

Answer (score 2):

This pretty well covers it:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

A styled unordered list, labels and inputs.